# Variable is linked in two components vue js

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, components

I just want to use an independant component many times like this :

```
<main-component>
   <other-component />
   <other-component />
</main-component>
```

I have a problem with variable in my other-component.
In the code bellow I use show var to display or not content according button click. I want to display only the paragraph of the current component clicked

```
import otherComponent from '../../otherComponent'

// main component
export default {
name: 'main-component',
  components: {
    otherComponent
  },
  data () {
    return {
    }
  },
}

<template>
  <div>
     <other-component />
     <other-component />
  </div>
</template>

// other component

export default {
name: 'other-component',
  data () {
    return {
      show: false
    }
  },
  methods: {
    toggle(){
      this.show = !this.show
    }
}

<template>
  <div>
    <button @click="toggle">Toggle</button>
    <p v-show="show">1</p>
  </div>
</template
```

When I click in button the two p are displayed. Why ?

Comment: can you provide a codepen or similar of it not working. It seems to [work](https://code.sololearn.com/WR5M8D2c6ayf#html) for me.

Answer (score 0):

If you nest components inside one another, you need to use slots: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-slots.html#ad.

For the following code to render correctly:

```html
<main-component>
  <other-component />
  <other-component />
</main-component>
```

Your `main-component` component needs to have `<slot />` in it's template:

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <slot />
  </div>
</template>
```

Then `<slot />` will be replaced by ...

```html
<other-component />
<other-component />
```

...when it renders. Which means `main-component` does not need to import or have any reference to `otherComponent`.

I have an example on CodeSandbox of this working: https://codesandbox.io/embed/vue-template-gblx0.